# Conditionally combine words from separate columns in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, grepl

I have a dataframe with 3 columns, all of which are characters. I want to use this dataframe to create formulas, so I need to make sure the data frame is formatted so I can paste them into equations.

The 1st column contains statistical functions (e.g. log10, exp). The 2nd contains an explanatory variable. The 3rd column contains information on the type of model, and this should be used to define whether the following function should be applied.

I want to edit the 2nd column so that it puts the letters from the 1st column at the front of the string. But I would like the text in the second column parenthesized. And I would only like to apply this function on certain models in the 3rd column, which contain a certain word. So some example data:

```
Function <- c("exp","log10","exp")
Variable <- c("x","y","z")
Model_type <- c("Model_Yes","Model_Yes","Model_No")
Test <- data.frame(Function,Variable,Model_type)
Test[, ] <- lapply(Test[, ], as.character)
```

I thought based on similar questions like [How to use chained ifelse and grepl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46442765/how-to-use-chained-ifelse-and-grepl) that I would need something like this:

```
Test$Variable <- ifelse((grepl("No", Test$Model_type)),
                    Test$Variable,
                    paste(Test$Function,Test$Variable))
```

But this doesn't work for the 'No' Model_types and also doesn't place brackets around the original Variable string. Here is what I would like the output to be.

```
Test$Variable <- c("exp(x)","log10(y)","z")
```

Thank you in advance for any help with this.

Comment: Yes that works perfectly for the Yes models. I've now realised that I need to put 'paste(Test$Variable),' in the second line for the No models. Happy to tick your answer if you put this below. Thank you!

Comment: code from @RonakShah should do with slight modification: either define your `data.frame` with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` or, put `as.character(Test$Variable)` in the "TRUE" part of the `ifelse`

Comment: the problem is `Test$Variable` is a `factor` not a `character` so if you don't convert it, its level is displayed instead of the label

Comment: Oh ok I somehow missed that. Thank you!

Comment: I have now changed the structure of the data frame so that all columns are characters, not factors. Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could paste the variables together using `paste0` and adding lagging and leading brackets

```
paste0(Test$Function, "(", Test$Variable, ")")   
#[1] "exp(x)"   "log10(y)" "exp(z)"
```

So, the final command would be

```
Test$Variable <- with(Test, ifelse(grepl("No", Model_type),
                      as.character(Variable), paste0(Function, "(", Variable, ")")))

Test
#  Function Variable Model_type
#1      exp   exp(x)  Model_Yes
#2    log10 log10(y)  Model_Yes
#3      exp        z   Model_No
```